# SSDT using multiple input fields in expression to create hyperlink

Tags: html, url, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I am building an expression for a hyperlink in SSDT but I am trying to build it with 2 field inputs.
Here is what I started with in the expression box and it works.

="http://s1324.com/Report&Car=Toyota&Model=Celica"

Then i substituted Celica for  &Fields!Model.Value and that URL worked. (where Fields!Model.Value = Celica)

="http://s1324.com/Report&Car=Toyota&Model="&Fields!Model.Value

Now i am trying to also substitute the word Toyota for a Car value (where Fields!Car.Value = Toyota) but i cant seem to complete the entire correct url

="http://s1324.com/Report&Car="&Fields!Car.Value"&Model="&Fields!Model.Value

Is there a way to use 2 inputs to create a URL?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the ampersands in the middle part. Try this

```
="http://s1324.com/Report&Car=" & Fields!Car.Value & "&Model=" & Fields!Model.Value
```

If you put spaces between operators it's easier to read